# @media(max-width:1200px) is not responding until 1183px

Tags: html, css

As title says, max-width is not working properly. You can see on pictures below what I mean. I'm posting only 1 section of it, but it doesn't work on whole site. Its not only for 1200px. I'm using $lg which is 992px but it applies @media code at 981px, same as for other values.
CSS is written in SCSS.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMFGl.jpg)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWp2r.jpg)

```
 .button-holder //button on the left css
    {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        width:300px;
        height:60px;
        //width:30%;
        background-color:$primary-light;
        font-weight: 600;
        border:3px solid $primary;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        a
        {
            width:100%;
            color:black;
        }

    }
    .line // line in middle
    {
        margin-left: 10px;
        border:1px solid $primary-light;
    }
    .square // square on image
    {
        height:15px;
        width:15px;
        background-color:$primary;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
.lower-back // 2nd last button from below
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        width:100%;
        margin-top:30px;
        .line
        {
            width:530px;
            @media(max-width:1200px)
            {
                width:150px;
            }
        }

    }
```

I am not using @media anywhere else in that section.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Have you used `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` in your HTML ?

Comment: Is 17px the default width of your browser's scrollbar (it is on mine - Chrome/Edge Windows 10).

Comment: @icebug yes i used it.

Comment: @ahaworth i guess it is, i didn't notice it so far. Thanks